# What design pattern can I use to represent processing data from any stream?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading data from a stream in buffered series of bytes (say 1024 bytes at a time) and do some comparison, checking, or processing, before writing it back to the same type of stream.

Currently data comes from file.  But in the future it may come from other sources (memorymapped file, TCP etc)

Is there a design pattern I can implement?  Or is that not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework provides the [Stream abstract class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) for this purpose.

.NET offers a number of [Stream Reader and Writer objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) out of the box.  One of those may already fit your needs, or you can inherit from `Stream` in a new class, and write your own custom implementation.

Comment: Can I just use Stream in place of an interface.  So comsume a stream object, but when I actually pass it the object, it can be something a FileStream, or MemoryStream, and they will all work the same way.

Comment: @erotavlas: If they all share a common interface or superclass, and your variable's type is of that interface/class, then yes.  That's exactly what interfaces and inheritance are made for.

Comment: That seems to be some COM interface, I've never seen it used in a .Net application. Instead, you should use the abstract `Stream` class.

Comment: @svick: Oh, you know what?  I think you're right.  I always use one of the descendants of Stream, so I seldom think much about the base class.  I'll edit to fix.